# Why these two print different output related with python =(assign) symbol

Tags: python

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

class Solution(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
        """
        :type l1: ListNode
        :type l2: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        def printListNode(y):
            print "start"
            while y:
                print y.val
                y = y.next
            print "end"
        temp = ListNode(0)
        result = temp
        while l1 and l2:
            if l1.val < l2.val:
                result.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                result.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next
            result = result.next
        printListNode(temp)
        printListNode(result)
        if l1:
            result.next = l1
        if l2:
             result.next = l2
        return temp.next

if __name__ == "__main__":
    solution = Solution()
    test1 = ListNode(2)
    test1.next = ListNode(3)
    test2 = ListNode(1)
    test2.next = ListNode(4)
    print(solution.mergeTwoLists(test1, test2))
```

As you can see I have printListNode(temp) and printListNode(result). What confused me is they print different result... for temp: it print 0,1,2,3 But for result: just 3. Why? I think result = temp means result equals to temp...

Comment: well seeing how you have `temp` set as nodes `0->1->2->3` and then you over write  `result` to be only node 3 in the while loop, I don't see what's the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have updated `result` with different value inside loop

```
        result = temp     # <- assigning value of  temp to result
        while l1 and l2:
            if l1.val < l2.val:
                result.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                result.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next
            result = result.next   # <- assigning rsult.next to result
        printListNode(temp)
        printListNode(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You assigned temp to ListNode(0) after this assignment and this remained unchanged when u called the printListNode function

```
 temp = ListNode(0);
```

Then u assigned result to be same as temp, only at this moment they are the same.

```
result = temp;
```

However inside the loop, u modified the content of result under these possible executions

```
result.next = l1;
result.next = l2;
result = result.next;
```

temp is still unchanged . Hence they  will have different result.